# Do something when ember is done with DOM updates

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to do stuff when ember bindings have synchronized and the DOM is again up to date.

I have tried with a callback from the function that manipulates the binded model, DOM is not updated when callback is executed.

I have tried with an observer directly on the model, DOM is not updated when the observer is executed.

I have tried with an observer on the binding, DOM is not updated when the observer is executed.

e.g.

```
App.view = Ember.View.extend({
    modelBinding: 'App.model',
    modelChanged : function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }.observes('model'),

    getMore: function(event) {
        App.set('model', "somethingnew");
    }
});
```

When I fire the "gotMore", I update the model, and when the model is updated and its changes have been rendered I want to scroll down.

In none of the ways I've tried have I been able to get the new scrollHeight. It is set a few ms after these events.

Here's an example on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/15/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to do this is documented here:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_next

```
modelChanged : function() {
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    $('body').append('New scroll height: '+document.body.scrollHeight);
  });
}.observes('content')
```

Comment: Had been banging my head for this for 3 days now. Somehow, this didn't appear in any of my searches. This works like a charm. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Ember.run.next`

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/run_loop.js#L531-566

```
App.view = Ember.View.extend({
    modelBinding: 'App.model',
    modelChanged : function() {
        Ember.run.next(myContext, function(){
            // code to be executed in the next RunLoop, which will be scheduled after the current one
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
    }.observes('model'),

    getMore: function(event) {
        App.set('model', "somethingnew");
    }
});
```

**Update**

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/hZ7Vx/

What you need is to run your code after the runloop that renders the `Ember.CollectionView` that the `{{each}}` helper would create.

*JavaScript*:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.model = Ember.Object.create({
    items: [1]
});

App.view = Ember.Handlebars.EachView.extend({
    contentBinding: 'App.model.items',

    itemViewClass: Ember._MetamorphView.extend({
        templateName: 'the_template'
    }),

    modelChanged : function() {
        Ember.run.next(this, function(){
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
            $('body').append('New scroll height: '+document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
    }.observes('content'),

    theAction: function(event) {
        App.controller.doStuffToModel();
    }
});

App.controller = Ember.Object.create({
    doStuffToModel : function() {
        App.model.set('items', [1,2,3,4,5]);
    }
});
```

*Handlebars*:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="the_template">
    <div style="height:200px;"></div> 
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view App.view}}
</script>​
```

Comment: The scheduling is working as expected and the closure is executed as the last thing in my code.  document.body.scrollHeight however, still differs from what i get in a `setTimeout(function() {console.log(document.body.scrollHeight);}, 2);` (not 1 :))

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle so I can see a full working example of what you're doing? Oh and use `Ember.run.later` instead of `setTimeout` (starts at line 402 in run_loop.js file linked above).

Comment: Here's jsFiddle example: [http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/15/)