# Ember JS- Apply jQuery after a component is entirely rendered

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm a beginner in ember and trying to implement a jQuery block to display my objects one after the other with a delay of 0.5 seconds.

My current code to display my ember objects is something like below

```
{{#if isBusy}}
  <div>Loading..</div>
{{else}}
  {{#if areLeads}}
    {{#each lead in leads}}
      <div>lead.title</div>
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <div>No Leads</div>
  {{/unless}}
{{/if}}
```

Now, what I want exactly is that after the leads are ready to be displayed, my code should execute, as in when `isBusy` is false.

The following is something that I've tried

```
_animateLeads: ->
    alert()

didInsertElement: ->
   Ember.run.scheduleOnce 'afterRender', @, => @_animateLeads()
```

However, the alert pop-ups as soon as the page starts to load. I'm not much aware of the ember concepts and learning the same.

Please guide me as to how to proceed and let me know if I should provide other details. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Update**

I ended up withe the following code

```
 _animateLeads: Ember.observer 'leads', ->
     if @get('leads')
         $('li.leads-list-lead').each (i) ->
           $(this).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000*i).fadeIn(2000);
           return

 _animateOnInsert: (->
   Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', @, @_animateLeads)
 ).on('didInsertElement')
```

but the following works only when changes to the `leads` is made. Initially, when the page is loaded, the leads do not appear as expected i,e. in the animated way. The following also works, but again, only when the `leads` is changed

```
_animateLeads: (->
    if @get('leads')
      $('li.leads-list-lead').each (i) ->
        $(this).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000*i).fadeIn(2000);
).observes('leads')
```

**Solution**

I ended up up the following code by mixing what i was doing above that works for me.

```
  _animateLeads: (->
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', @, @_animateActiveLeads)
  ).observes('leads')

  _animateActiveLeads: (->
   if @get('leads') && @get('leadDisplay') == 'active'
     $('li.is-online').each (i) ->
       $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
  )
```

A similar question is asked as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686670/do-something-when-ember-is-done-with-dom-updates) that did not come up in my searches earlier. The accepted answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component hook you are probably looking for is `afterRender`, which will give you access to the DOM after it has rendered. If you load all your div elements as hidden and then use jQuery to show them you should get roughly what you are after.

At the moment `liquid-fire` (the go-to addon for animations in Ember) doesn't help with animating lists. There is a future underlying library designed to run beneath liquid-fire (https://github.com/ember-animation/ember-animated) which supports it, but it's not even alpha yet. If you are just getting started with Ember it would probably be best to steer clear of that for now ...

Comment: You're right about `afterRender` and as you see that's what tried initially. However, i changed bits and pieces and was able to make it work. Though facing another issue. I'll post my code in a while

Comment: Could you look at the updated code and description? Thanks

Comment: I figured later that by `afterRender`, you meant it as a method like `_animateLeads`. Anyways, i found ended up with the above solution that works for me. Thanks for you guidance. Appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Two other things. 1. It looks like you are using CoffeeScript? The consensus in the Ember community is that CoffeeScript should probably be avoided at this point, now that ES6 provides many of the same benefits. 2. If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer here, it will help level me up so I can better help people learn Ember :-)

Comment: :D Definitely for accepting the answer. Regarding usage of CoffeeScript, i'm actually making changes in an existing project and can't avoid using it. Though, i'll remember this tip when working from Scratch. Thanks. If its not much, can you possibly have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705793/ember-sort-my-records-so-the-null-for-a-column-are-retuned-first) other question. I've made it work but can't understand the reason. If you could help, it would be wonderful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look is about [Promise()](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/classes/Promise). This is an async call. It doesn't mean that after your element has been inserted that it will be ready. It can take 0.5s, 1s, 5s...

You should also look into [ember-concurrency](https://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs/introduction) because it makes this kind of wokr much easier.

With that said you should do something like this:

```
leads: this.get('store').findAll('leads').then(function(leads) {
   //loaded
})
```

Also, if you are looking for animations take a look into [liquid-fire](https://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/)

Comment: I believe the question is about how to animate in a list of elements after the data has loaded ...

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand you. However, @acorncom is correct about the animation.